# Flask redirect on button click not happening

Tags: redirect, flask

I'm still trying to learn flask/redirects/etc in general. I tried to create a simple page with a submit button, and when I submit, redirects to a page which show json data. But nothing happens when I click the button. I can access end point in my browser url.

This is how my understanding works. Please point out where I'm misunderstanding it.

1. Serve the `index.html`.
2. I have a form (Submit button) which has the `POST` method in the `index.html`.
3. When I click the submit button, it should redirect me to the page which has the `jsonify` of the data.

The reason I'm using jsonify is because this is part of a bigger step I'm trying to take, where I click the button, it queries a database and returns a json of the resultproxy. This I think I will have to do with AJAX. I still have to figure things out.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, url_for, jsonify
from forms import Submit
import os
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(12)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    form = Submit()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return redirect(url_for('data'))
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/data')
def data():
    data = {
        'author': 'rowling',
        'book': 'harry potter'
    }
    return jsonify(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import validators, SubmitField


class Submit(FlaskForm):
    submit = SubmitField(label='submit')
```

**index.html**

```
<h1>Hello world</h1>

<br>
<br>

<form action="{{url_for ('data') }}" method="GET">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" action="{{url_for ('data') }}">
</form>
```

Comment: I solved it by changing the `<input type="button">` to `{{ form.submit() }}`. I don't understand why the latter works but not the former. Will appreciate it if anyone can help me understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at your template, the form was defined to submit with GET method, instead of POST method:

```html
<form action="{{url_for ('data') }}" method="GET">
```

Besides, the action URL was set to `/data` instead of `/`. IMO, you will need to change this line to this:

```html
<form method="post">
```

Also, you have to add `type="submit"` to your `<input>` or `<button>` element to make it submit form:

```html
<input type="submit">
```

Since you use WTForms, just use `{{ form.submit }}` to render your submit button. The final form will be:

```html
<form method="post">
    {{ form.submit }}
</form>
```

Just give it a try and let me konw if it works!

Comment: I noticed the `GET` and changed to `POST`. But it does not work. I removed the `action=` also. Still doesn't redirect... This is my form currently `<form method="POST">
    <input type="button" value="Submit">
    </form>`

Comment: `<input type="submit">` this is what helped. Thanks a lot.